# asp.net mvc returning an image in an iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc

what i want i want to return a complete image from the controller that is uploaded. i want to display the complete image returning as the part of iframe response. here is my view code to get the idea. can it be done? Currently it is returning a string that a file is uploaded or not?

```
  <form action="<%= Url.Action("FileUpload", "Organization")%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="uploadresult" onsubmit="return showStatus()">
           <input type="file" id="a" name="a" />



            <iframe id="uploadResult" name="uploadresult"  width="200" frameborder="0" height="100" onload="showResult();" style="visibility:hidden">                  
            </iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(CompletePhysicalPath, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg");
```