# How to return image from controller without setting Content-Disposition tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

So I'm using MVC **2** to serve up some images from a Controller Action.  General wisdom ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416145/asp-net-mvc-returning-an-image-in-an-iframe), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379614/display-image-from-image-object-in-mvc)) seems to be to use one of the `FileResult` types (`FileStreamResult`, `FileContentResult` or `FileContentResult').

All three concrete `FileResult`'s, however, set the `Content-Disposition` response header with `attachment; filename{YourFileNameHere}=UTF-8`.  The net result is that if a user views my image directly, rather than embedded in HTML, the browser present a save dialog, rather than displaying the image.  I would prefer the image simply display in the browser.

I guess that makes my question: Using MVC 2 What is the appropriate way to return an image result where the image is *NOT* marked for download?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MVC framework uses the FileResult.FileDownloadName property to determine whether to send the content inline or as an attachment.  If you're instantiating a FileResult-derived type directly, don't set its FileDownloadName property.  Alternatively, if you're using the Controller.File factory methods, call an overload which doesn't take a *fileDownloadName* argument (or pass in null for that argument).